# Lost apps during jailbreak

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, ios

I lost some functions of my iPhone 4 with iOS 7 after jailbreak like making phone calls, the camera app, and others too. I don't want to remove the jailbreak.

Comment: Restore your iPhone to factory settings and re-jailbreak?

Answer (score 1):

This problem was happened for me on my iPhone 4 with iOS 7 when there was few free space (less than 1GB) with lots of apps on it. The only solution that helps me was disabling `find my iPhone`, full backup with iTunes and manual backup the data of Messages and other apps with iExplorer and PhoneView. And then restore the iOS 7 again and jailbreak.
Because there wont be any iOS updates after 7.1.2 you will not lose the jailbreak opportunity.